# Scraped img src outputting into base64

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, base64

I'm trying to scrape just the `https://` link:

```
src ="https://static.daraz.com.bd/p/apple-1088-5942-1-catalog.jpg"
```

from the below code using **BeautifulSoup4 Python library**.

```
<div class="image-wrapper default-state">
      <img class="lazy image -loaded" alt="Macbook Air (MD711ZA/B) - Aluminum - Laptop - Dual-Core Intel Core i5 - 4GB RAM - 128GB HDD - 11.6&amp;#039;&amp;#039; LED - Intel HD Graphics 5000 - Mac OS X Mountain Lion 10.8" data-image-vertical="1" width="176" height="220" src="https://static.daraz.com.bd/p/apple-1088-5942-1-catalog.jpg" data-sku="AP113ELAA1XBNAFAMZ" data-placeholder="placeholder_daraz.jpg" style="display: inline-block;">
      <noscript>&lt;img src="https://static.daraz.com.bd/p/apple-1088-5942-1-catalog.jpg" width="176" height="220" class="image" /&gt;
      </noscript>
</div>
```

But I'm getting output like this:

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7
```

Any way to get the original `src link` ?

BeautifulSoup code :

```
for image in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'image-wrapper default-state'}):
            print image.img['src']
```

The same code is working in other sites and getting the src link. But only here it's outputting into base64 format.

Comment: Post the code you're using. You're scraping the data of the src instead of the src text.

Comment: @EugeneK Added the code in the post. Kindly check again. :)

Comment: Seems to work for me with your provided sample as well.

Comment: @EugeneK Are you getting this: `https://static.daraz.com.bd/p/apple-1088-5942-1-catalog.jpg"` ? I need the src link not the base64 format.

Comment: Yes that's what I get. Check your proxy/noscript settings. Or print out the html that bs4 is actually parsing. `print(soup.prettify())` might tell you something.

Comment: @EugeneK It would be much helpful if describe the procedure of proxy/nonscript setting. I'm very new to this.

Comment: I don't know how you're actually getting the html. If you're using `requests` or `urllib`, something might be getting html that you're not expecting for whatever reason.

Comment: @EugeneK Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91943/discussion-between-s4dman-and-eugene-k).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converted the whole `img` tag into `string` and then I found out that the `tag` they were using was `<data-img src=" ">`

So then I just simply used that `tag` and got my expected output.

```
for image in soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class': 'image-wrapper'}):
    print image.img['data-src']
```